# 22.04.3-desktop-amd64 (LTS) install hangs, need help

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, raid

I'm desperate. Tried many things, on my own and as I found online, with no success. (Almost) every time I get to the screen that shows the "splash slides" and a spinning mouse cursor but, other than the slides changing, nothing seems to be happening in any alternative. My network router indicates no traffic with the system unless I explicitly want to cause it (from a terminal window, Ctrl+Alt+T). There is no progress bar shown. I only saw a bit of a log shown under the splash screen once but it ended up the same ... and it matches what I saw otherwise in /var/log/installer/debug and, perhaps, syslog (don't remember).

The messages that I was able to see (unsure of order at this point, please excuse typos - I retyped those from screenshots I made using my phone):

```
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR (/run/user/999) is not owned by us (uid 0), but by uid 999! (This could e.g. happen if you try to connect to a non-root PulseAudio as a root user, over the native protocol. Don't do that.)
```

```
/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/frontend/gtk_components/nmwidgets.py:19: Warning: Source id 6242 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self.timeout_id)
/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/frontend/gtk_components/nmwidgets.py:135: Warning: Source id 6336 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self.rows_changed_id)
```

Note: I've seen multiple different line numbers and source ids.

When I choose the option to "Erase disk...", when I get to the dialog to enter my and computer's name, username, etc., while doing so, a popup appears:

> **Do you want to resume partitioning?**
>
> The attempt to mount a file system with type vfat in /dev/nvme0n1p1 at /boot/efi failed.
>
> You may resume partitioning from the partitioning menu.
>
> [Go back] [Continue]

**EDIT / Perhaps important note:** As you will see in my system description below, the drive indicated in the message above is nvme0, which is the primary (presently bootable) Windows drive, while I am trying to install Ubuntu into nvme1.

I did try the `noacpi` suggestion I found online within grub. I also tried both downloading updates and proprietary software and also tried with neither (no updates, no proprietary software). I did not observe any difference.

*BTW, the message next to the proprietary software checkbox contains a sentence "Some is proprietary." That does not sound correct. It should be either "Some **are**" or "**One** is".*

I'm booting this Ubuntu install from a 16GB USB stick created by Rufus. My system is complex desktop (well, *floor*top), as follows:

- Motherboard: ASUS ROG Crosshair VIII Formula, with most up-to-date BIOS available.
- CPU: AMD Ryzen 9 5950X, 3.4 GHz, water cooled (NZXT)
- RAM: 64 GB
- Graphics: EVGA GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, connected to two monitors, one 2560x1600 (Dell 3008WFP, connected via dual-link DVI), another 4K (Dell S3221QS, connected via HDMI). Both are detected and picture shows up on both but by the time the install choices dialog is shown the 4K one goes to sleep with the dialog in it, not the one that remains visible. I worked around this by disconnecting the 4K monitor before or during install.
- NVMe storage with AMD RAID (RAIDXpert2) enabled (don't ask why, now I wouldn't do it):

  - nvme0: Samsung 970 EVO Plus 2TB with Windows 11 already there. I need to keep this and dual boot with it. This is the Windows boot drive, C:.
  - **nvme1: Corsair Force MP500 480 GB (empty), to be dedicated to this Ubuntu install entirely.**
- SATA storage on the primary controller: three RAID mirror HDD pairs, all with NTFS file systems

  - 2x WDC WD161KFGX (2x 16TB mirror = 16TB total)
  - 2x WDC WD40EZRX (2x 4TB mirror = 4 TB total)
  - 2x WDC WD30EZRX (2x 3TB mirror = 3 TB total)
- SATA storage on the extra controller this motherboard comes with:

  - 1x Seagate ST32000542AS (2TB standalone, NTFS)
  - 1x LG BH16 Blu-ray/DVD Writer (HL-DT-ST BD-RE BH16NS40)
- Network

  - Wired network (Gigabit Ethernet) connection to my Internet router. Connectivity does work - tested from terminal when the install hung.
  - WiFi antenna connected.
- All powered with a 1000W EVGA power supply (EVGA 1000 G2).
- Also connected via USB:

  - 16GB USB stick with Ubuntu 22.04.3-desktop-amd64
  - Logitech BRIO webcam
  - Blue Yeti microphone
  - Cannon CanoScan LiDE 700F flatbed scanner
  - WACOM Intuos CTH-680 tablet (CTH-680/S)
  - Back-UPS RS 1300G external UPS connected via USB as well
  - Two additional USB hubs

Additional note: the keyboard, mouse and the 4K Dell S3221QS monitor are connected via 4-port Aimos KVM switch (AIMOSKVM-401). This appears to work fine.

Please help. I have not had this much trouble installing Ubuntu on other bare metal and VMs before but this is the first time I am trying with this, my main, system. I am not a complete rookie (I do develop software running on Linux among other things) but am not to be considered a Linux (install, setup, config) expert either - nowhere near.

Comment: It isn't clear in your message if you were able to boot into Ubuntu with just the USB stick.  I haven't installed 22.04 recently, but I think there should be an option to "Install" or "Try" Ubuntu.  Were you able to get this?  And if so, instead of installing, can you try it and does it run ok?  Something else you can consider is to try a newer version of Ubuntu like 23.04.  I wouldn't worry about `Warnings` or typos (i.e., is/are).  I think they're distracting you from the problem at hand.  Also, see if you can try the USB on another computer, just to rule out issues with the USB drive.

Comment: Yes, I was able to boot into it - everything is coming from there. All these refer to "Try or install Ubuntu". I don't have a good secondary computer to play with, but I could recreate the stick.

Comment: Like you, I have installed Ubuntu many times before but wouldn't call myself an expert in installing it (after all, we only have to do it once per computer...in theory...).  When I encounter problems such as your's, I tend to try another version of Ubuntu.  This is easier than figuring out the cause -- and it usually works...  Also, looking over your post again, you have lots of peripherals attached.  I guess you can detach them for the installation, just in case any of them are the cause (probably not).

Comment: Thanks. Will try with 23.04 - downloading now. That won't stop me from wondering what is this about, trying to learn. If anyone can help/clarify, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Tried with 23.04. The installation window disappeared, leaving the rest of the desktop. Without restarting the OS, I ran it a few times. Found "ubuntu_desktop_installer: ../nouveau/pushbuf.c:730: nouveau_pushbuf_data: Assertion `kref' failed" in logs. I finally gave up and decided to reboot back to Windows to research more. I then noticed that my 2nd SSD did have a bootable Ubuntu volume ... and tried it. It worked. I'm unsure of its state, although it seems to work.

Comment: That's interesting...  It sounds like Ubuntu did get installed either with 23.04 or 22.04, and the errors you were encountering with the installer were happening towards the end of the installation process?  (i.e., after most of the copying was done)  I wouldn't worry about its state -- if you can boot from it and use it, then its fine.  If programs are missing, you can always install them manually yourself afterwards.  Good luck!

Comment: I know it wasn't 22.04. Things do appear to work.